# convert JAXBElement<String> value to java string

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2-basics

I have a `pojo class` where return type of variable is `JAXBElement<String>`. I want to store it in a `String`. **Can someone explain how to do it?**

```
File file = new File("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/JubulaXMLFiles/DemoWithDrools_1.0.xml");    
        
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Content.class);    
     
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();    
        
        Content e=(Content) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);    
        String retrivedValue = (String)e.getProject().getName().toString();
        System.out.println(retrivedValue);
```

Output is like `javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement@5a99da`. But I want to retrieve the **string** value in `retrivedValue`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `getProject()` returns the type `JAXBElement<String>` then `getName()` returns the name of the XML tag. To get the value of that element you need to call `getValue()`.

Find below a small snippet

```
QName qualifiedName = new QName("", "project");
JAXBElement<String> project = new JAXBElement<>(qualifiedName, 
        String.class, null, "funnyCoding");
System.out.printf("getName()  - %s%n", project.getName());
System.out.printf("getValue() - %s%n", project.getValue());
```

output

```
getName()  - project
getValue() - funnyCoding
```